# for while if loop nested error message if nothing found

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

```
                String aaa= "password";
                int wloop = 0;
                while (wloop<myarraylist.size()) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < myarraylist.size(); i++) {
                        Something qwerty = myarraylist.get(i);
                        String bbb= qwerty.getinfor();

                        if (aaa.equals(bbb)) {
                            System.out.println("you have found it!");
                            wloop = myarraylist.size();

                        }wloop++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("nothing have been found");
                }
```

---

I have an arraylist of things I want to iterate over with a for loop. Everytime it iterates, I get an object from the arraylist. and I get its information in a String format. if I find the string "password"  in the objects information, I want to printout a msg onscreen saying "I have founded it".

you may assume that I will only find the String "password" only once.

If however after looping through the entire arraylist, I want the message "nothing have been found" to be printed onscreen.

***However***

As it is currently written, "nothing have been found" will always print to screen no matter what happens. I am having trouble making nothing happening in a for loop where after every iteration (where each one is being examined by an if statement) being a condition to proc an action. I tried putting the entire for loop inside an if statement, but had trouble with adding "return true" somewhere.

Comment: Setting `wloop = arraylist.size()` to force the loop to exit looks like you're trying to "trick" the loop into exiting.  Don't use tricky code when you can use straightforward code that makes it clear what you're doing.  In this case, `break`.

Comment: thank you! when we were taught loops, we weren't told about breaks in class. now i know.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8+, you can use a `Stream` and `anyMatch` to to determine if there is a match. Like,

```
if (myarraylist.stream().anyMatch(qwerty -> aaa.equals(qwerty.getinfor()))) {
    System.out.println("you have found it");
} else {
    System.out.println("nothing found");
}
```

In earlier versions, you need a *flag*. And you don't need a nested loop, but I would prefer a `for-each` loop. Something like,

```
boolean found = false;
for (Something qwerty : myarraylist) {
    if (aaa.equals(qwerty.getinfor())) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    System.out.println("you have found it");
} else {
    System.out.println("nothing found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to set the status of password found our not and depending on that you can print the statement. Maybe something like this:

```
            String aaa= "password";
            int wloop = 0;
            boolean isPasswordFound = false;
            while (wloop<myarraylist.size()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < myarraylist.size(); i++) {
                    Something qwerty = myarraylist.get(i);
                    String bbb= qwerty.getinfor();

                    if (aaa.equals(bbb)) {
                        System.out.println("you have found it!");
                        isPasswordFound = true;
                        wloop = myarraylist.size();

                    }wloop++;
                }
                if(!isPasswordFound) {
                    System.out.println("nothing have been found");
                }

            }
```

Comment: This might be a solution. But do we really need two loops?

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik Only providing the solution to what is asked and not doing the whole optimisation.

Comment: thank you for both of your help. any points of view are helpful because  i am new computer science student from september. it's helpful to see multiple ways of doing something. i have to sleep now. but i upvoted both your answers.